# Aten CS22U hotkey scroll lock not switching desktops

Tags: kvm-switch

I brought this new Aten CS22U KVM switch, but when I press scroll lock twice on my keyboard, it does not switch desktops :(, does my new KVM switch not have the hotkey feature ? The Aten switch in my office does it, am not sure about the model though.

If it does not, is there something I could download or set manually to make it switch desktops with hotkeyS. What if that soft little coin like button that comes along with the Aten CS22U get spoiled ???

Answer (score 0):

Scroll lock is not enabled by default in Ubuntu.
Try to enabled it with:

```
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

Be aware that when you restart this setting will be gone again. 
To make it permanent you can use a startup script which includes this command.

Another way is this small script which you can map to a key.

```
#!/bin/sh
notify-send \
        --icon=keyboard \
        --hint=int:transient:1 \
        --app-name=kvm \
        "Switching KVM input"

        xset led 3
        sleep 0.2
        xset -led 3
```